# How can I use my github profile SSH key to modify all my repos?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I've inserted a SSH key in my github profile, and then I tried to push some changes, but I received the error: Permission denied (public key). I tried the solutions of the GitHub Docs, but it didn't work for me, I even tried this:

> eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" && ssh-add ~/.ssh/directorytokey

How can I modify my repos with SSH if I have a SSH key set in my GitHub Profile?

Comment: Are your repo remotes set to have authentication through `ssh` or `https`?

Comment: You need to use the file name to the key, not just the directory name.  Once you've run `ssh-add`, `ssh-add -l` should list the keys you have available.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, the [GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent) does illustrate adding the *private* SSH key (not its parent folder) to ssh-agent

```sh
# start the ssh-agent in the background
$ eval `ssh-agent -s`
> Agent pid 59566
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

That being said, you can:

- start with a private key which is *not* passphrase protected first, for testing
- check if the key is properly detected/used with

  ```
    ssh -Tv git@github.com
    # or, for a custom key filename:
    ssh -Tv -i /path/to/my/private_key git@github.com
  ```

You should see a welcome message ('Hi, ...')